# Separar valores vindo de uma variavel

Tags: php, html

Ola amigos preciso separar valores de uma variavel recebo os valores assim:

```
-4.08768, -63.141322 23/04/2017 22:00:00
```

preciso dos valores separado cada um com uma variavel tipo assim:

-4.08768, -63.141322

23/04/2017

22:00:00

Preciso enviar via post para meu sistema mais nao estou conseguindo separar alguem da essa forca ai para separar isso exemplo:

```html
<?php
$variavel = "-4.08768, -63.141322 23/04/2017 22:00:00";
echo $variavel;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$variavel = "-4.08768, -63.141322 23/04/2017 22:00:00";
```

Primeiro retiramos o espaço depois da virgula para depois fazermos um explode com espaço de modo a não separar a latitude da longitude

```
$variavel=str_replace(", ",",",$variavel);
```

O explode

```
$partes = explode(' ',$variavel);

$coordenadas=$partes[0];
$data=$partes[1];
$hora=$partes[2];
```

E finalmente recolocamos o espaço após a virgula na variável $coordenadas

```
$coordenadas=str_replace(",", ",",$coordenadas);
```

A saída será

```
echo $coordenadas; //-4.08768, -63.141322
echo $data; //23/04/2017
echo  $hora; //22:00:00
```

> Juntando tudo:

```
$variavel = "-4.08768, -63.141322 23/04/2017 22:00:00";
$variavel=str_replace(", ",",",$variavel);
$partes = explode(' ',$variavel);
$coordenadas=$partes[0];
$data=$partes[1];
$hora=$partes[2];
$coordenadas=str_replace(",", ",",$coordenadas);

echo $coordenadas;
echo $data;
echo  $hora;
```

[**exemplo- ideone**](https://ideone.com/8ya16d)

> O mesmo resultado se obtém da seguinte forma:

```
$variavel = "-4.08768, -63.141322 23/04/2017 22:00:00";

$partes = explode(' ',$variavel);

$latitude=$partes[0]; //-4.08768,
$longitude=$partes[1]; //-63.141322
$data=$partes[2]; //23/04/2017
$hora=$partes[3]; // 22:00:00

$latLong=$latitude." ".$longitude; // -4.08768, -63.141322
```

[**exemplo - ideone**](https://ideone.com/QWce8T)

Answer (score 0):

Use um explode para fazer a separação da forma que precisar ex:

```
$params = explode(',', $row['variavel']);
$lat = $params[0]; //-4.08768
$lon = $params[1]; //-63.141322 23/04/2017 22:00:00
$val = $params[2]; //0

$saida = $lon.','.$val.','.$lat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-split.php), você informa o `pattern` `regex` para que a `string` seja dividida:

```
$variavel = "-4.08768, -63.141322 23/04/2017 22:00:00";

$split = preg_split("/\b\s/", $variavel);

var_dump($split);
```

Dessa forma, retornará um `array` com três posições:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(20) "-4.08768, -63.141322"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "23/04/2017"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "22:00:00"
}
```

Veja o exemplo no [ideone](http://ideone.com/7XwMvc)